# Neural network for a simple game?

Tags: programming, machine-learning, neural-networks, game

I'm taking a class that is based on the Mathematica coding language, and we must do a 6-week final project. I am considering coding a neural network for a simple game like 2048, pacman, snake, etc. What all should i consider in choosing a game, and writing the network so that this project goes smoothly?

Comment: See [Teaching AI to play a game with Reinforcement Learning](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1379860) and [Reinforcement Q-Learning for Atari Games](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1380007)